# Run jQuery after setInterval function is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic count function and i wish to run some code only after the count function is complete. Is there a way of doing this simply?

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/vyN6V/243/

Current Code

```
    var number = 1500;
    var aValue = 300;

    function count(Item) {
        var current = aValue;
        Item.val(aValue += 1);
        if (current < number) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                count(Item)
            }, 0.1);
        }
    }

    count($(".input"));
    // code here should only run when count function is complete
```

I tried this, to no avail

```
    var number = 1500;
    var aValue = 300;

    function count(Item) {
        var current = aValue;
        Item.val(aValue += 1);
        if (current < number) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                count(Item)
            }, 0.1);
        }
    }

    count(function$(".input"){
      // code here should only run when count function is complete
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vyN6V/244/)

```
var number = 1500;
var aValue = 300;

function count(Item) {
    var current = aValue;
    Item.val(aValue += 1);
    if (current < number) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            count(Item)
        }, 0.1);
    } else {
        $('span').text('code here should only run when function count is complete');
    }
}

count($(".input"));
```